# Moving or Deleting Original Image Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

So I'm doing some work in Microsoft Powerpoint 2013 which has a heavy use of images.
If I were to email the file to someone else say, or delete or move the original images would the images still show?
Does powerpoint embed the images or is it just a link to the file?

Comment: Why can't you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not images are linked or embedded is your choice when you edit the presentation and insert the image.

[image]

By definition, linked images are not included in the presentation but only linked to the location where they are stored outside the presentation. If these images are moved or deleted from that storage place, the links will break and the image will not show in the presentation. Likewise, if the presentation is emailed to someone who does not have access to the link locations (with exactly the same path as defined in the presentation), the links will break.

[image]

To avoid that, open the presentation that shows all images intact, then click the File tab. Below the document information you will find `Edit Links to Files` if the presentation contains links. You can click each link and then the `Break Link` button to change the image from a linked to an embedded image.

[image]

If you don't see any links, everything is contained within the presentation and should survive sharing per email or deleting images in folders.